# "summing" two strings of numbers

Tags: c, string, char

Got an assignment today to sm up two strings of numbers.
For example:

```
string_1=123456789
string_2=987654321
```

Those are chars in those strings, and I can't figure out how can I do this.
I thought of using the ASCII table, by representing each char as the char value minus value of the char "a" and eventually get a number.
How can I arrange it inside a string later?

Comment: use `atoi` to convert string to integer equivalent but make sure you don't overflow the integer size during conversion and addition

Comment: `'0' - '0' == 0`, `'1' - '0' == 1`, ... `'9' - '0' == 9` and conversely `0 + '0' == '0'`, ... `9 + '0' == '9'`

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Is the string named `string_1` with set equal to the *String Literal* `"123456789"` or is the string literal the entire `"string_1=123456789"`. The first is trivial on a number of levels with either `sscanf` or `strtol` and the latter is simple matter of a slight difference in *format string* for `sscanf` or scanning forward with a pointer to locate the `'='` and beginning conversion with the next char with `strtol`. But which path to take depends on what the actual string is. Please clarify.

Comment: Is the goal to create a new string containing the sum, or to create an integer value that is the sum?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strtol()` C function to convert your string to int then do the sum.

```
char* stopped = nullptr;
int val1 = (int)strtol(str1, &stopped, 10);
if (*stopped) {
    /* handle error */
    return 1;
}
stopped = nullptr;
int val2 = (int)strtol(str2, &stopped, 10);
if (*stopped) {
    /* handle error */ 
    return 1;
}
int val3 = val1 + val2;
```

**Previous answer :**

> The atoi() function has been deprecated by strtol() and should not be used in new code.

source [Mac OS X Manual Page for atoi(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atoi.3.html)

And the `itoa()` function isn't standard. Your code will be more portable if you use `snprintf()`.

<s>Use the `atoi()` C function to convert your string to an int then do the sum and use `itoa()` to convert back to a string.</s>

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int val1 = atoi(str1);
int val2 = atoi(str2);

int val3 = val1 + val2;

char sum [33];
itoa(val3, sum, 10);
```

Comment: `strtol()` is a much better alternative.

Comment: Why using an overpowering function that need a ptr to give you the next character after the numerical part, if you don't need this info? `atoi()` is good in this situation.

Comment: `atoi("99887766554433221100")` returns `-1` with not even any indication of error.

Comment: @BSO It's not overpowering, it's just the correct one to be used. Example: compare scanf vs fgets for user inputs.

Comment: @SouravGhosh There isn't a correct one and a bad one, there is multiple ways of getting the result wanted, yes with `atoi()` you need to check the input you are giving to the function and in my opinion this isn't a bad idea

Comment: Did you miss the comment from @pmg ? Moreover, it's correct vs incorrect, not only _bad_. However, I'll stop commenting now.

Comment: @SouravGhosh & @pmg ok I checked and it's better to use `strtol()`, I updated my anwser, next time @SouravGhosh try to write a more constructive response with arguments not only "strtol() is a much better alternative."

Answer (score 0):

Here this is:

```
string findSum(string str1, string str2) 
{ 
    // Before proceeding further, make sure length 
    // of str2 is larger. 
    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) 
        swap(str1, str2); 

    // Take an empty string for storing result 
    string str = ""; 

    // Calculate length of both string 
    int n1 = str1.length(), n2 = str2.length(); 

    // Reverse both of strings 
    reverse(str1.begin(), str1.end()); 
    reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end()); 

    int carry = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<n1; i++) 
    { 
        // Do school mathematics, compute sum of 
        // current digits and carry 
        int sum = ((str1[i]-'0')+(str2[i]-'0')+carry); 
        str.push_back(sum%10 + '0'); 

        // Calculate carry for next step 
        carry = sum/10; 
    } 

    // Add remaining digits of larger number 
    for (int i=n1; i<n2; i++) 
    { 
        int sum = ((str2[i]-'0')+carry); 
        str.push_back(sum%10 + '0'); 
        carry = sum/10; 
    } 

    // Add remaining carry 
    if (carry) 
        str.push_back(carry+'0'); 

    // reverse resultant string 
    reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); 

    return str; 
}
```

Comment: Please note that this question is tagged as `C`. You may want to highlight the algorithm, rather than a possible `C++` implementation of it.